# How to prove only answer

Tags: number-theory

The question is

Find all prime numbers, $p$ such that $16p+1$ gives a perfect cube.

By trial and error, I have found 307 to be a solution but how do I prove that it is the only solution (if it is)?

I've got that $16p+1$ can only give odd solutions that end in $7,9,1,2,3$ but that's about it.

Comment: $16p = (n-1)(n^2+n+1)$, hence either $p|(n-1)$ or $p|(n^2+n+1)$ Now since $n^2 + n + 1$ is always odd, $16|(n-1)$ So $n$ is of the form $16k+1$. Can you proceed further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$16p+1=n^3\iff 16p=n^3-1$$
$$\iff 16p=(n-1)(n^2+n+1)$$
We know by trial an error that $p>16$, and 
$$n^2+n+1>n-1 \iff n^2>2 \implies n \ge 2$$
so we'll choose the factors accordingly.

Note: I concluded from the fact that $p>16$ and $n^2+n+1>n-1$ that to split factors, we have to have $n^2+n+1=kp$ where $k|16$ and thus $n-1=16/k$, and wrote down what happens in these cases.

First
$$n-1=16 \iff n=17$$
$$n^2+n+1=p \implies p=307$$
Second: note that 
$$n \equiv0,1 \pmod{2} \implies n^2+n+1 \equiv1 \pmod{2} \tag{1}$$
But since now $n^2+n+1 \ne p$ we must have $n^2+n+1 =kp$, where $k|16$ and $k \ne 1$ which contradicts with $(1)$

Comment: Good answer, +1

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Thanks ;)

Comment: "Note: I concluded from the fact that $p>16$ and $n^2+n+1>n−1$ that to split factors, we have to have $n^2+n+1=kp$ where $k|16$ and thus $n−1=16/k$, and wrote down what happens in these cases." I don't get why $n^2+n+1=kp$ where $k|16$

Comment: @sargon129 How would you normally distribute $16p$ among the $2$ factors $(n-1)(n^2+n+1)$? Of course, $n^2+n+1$ has to contain $p$ in it's factors, otherwise, it can't be because $p>16$ and $n^2+n+1>n-1$, if you chose $n^2+n+1$ without $p$, you'll have $n-1$ has $p$, and thus  $n-1>n^2+n+1$ which is impossible. So
$$n^2+n+1 \in \{p,2p,4p,8p,16p\}$$